# C++/CLI workaround for implementing a C++ interface

Tags: .net, c++-cli, abstract-class

Micropather requires users implement their abstract class "Graph" in order to use the library. What's a good way to do this from C++/CLI so I can use Micropather in .NET?

There are only two methods to implement:

```
virtual float LeastCostEstimate( void* stateStart, void* stateEnd ) = 0;
virtual void AdjacentCost( void* state, std::vector< StateCost > *adjacent ) = 0;
```

So far I have been scheming with gcroot and delegates, but I don't have anything solid yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write an ordinary C++ class that inherits `Graph`, and use the [gcroot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f%28VS.80%29.aspx) template to refer to CLR objects from within that class.

```
class MyGraph : public Graph
{
    gcroot<SomethingImportant ^> _stuff;

    // implement abstract memfuncs to call onto _stuff
};
```